How to propagate numpy.nan through comparisons in Pandas
Let's say
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, np.nan]})
df['B'] = df['A'] > 2

I want this to give
     A      B
0  1.0  False
1  3.0   True
2  NaN    NaN

but it gives
     A      B
0  1.0  False
1  3.0   True
2  NaN  False

How can I get the result I want, i.e. propagation of NaN when using boolean conditions? I have lots of these conditional expressions in my code and would like to avoid replacing them all with lambda functions or .map or .apply or np.where statements if possible.
I tried switching all the NaNs to pd.NA and this gives this desired result, but it seems it has to change the dtype to 'Int64' or 'Float64' to accommodate pd.NA which is then not compatible with other packages I'm using (specifically statsmodels raises a TypeError; seems to be a known compatibility issue). If anyone knows a way to make pd.NA compatible with standard data types like float and int then I would be happy to use that.

I edited this in the Staging Ground and I just want to mention: Technically this isn't a conditional; the example given (>) is a comparison.

pd.NA isn't compatible with standard datatype. For int: any combinason of bytes are valid numbers, so no NA nor NaN at all. For float, IEEE standard has coding for NaN. Note that it is quite logical that NaN>2 (and NaN<=2, both) is False. There would be also a certain logic in considering them NaN. But (float>float) type is bool. And, likewise, bool has only 2 values, True or False. There is no "NaN" in bool. And that is quite normal. You wouldn't want the type to force a bigger coding than the standard 1 bool=1 bit. And a bit has only 2 possible values.

While Float64>Float64 is a BooleanDType, another pandas non standard type, that have a NA value in addition to True and False (and therefore is obviously not just a single bit, exactly like a Int64 is obviously not just 64 bits). So they are at the liberty to decide that 2<NA is neither True nor False, but another thing. Which is clearly not possible with standard type. Again, a standard bool can't have more than 2 possible values. A standard int64, can't have more than 2⁶⁴ values (and they are all integers). A standard float can be NaN, but that's all for standard types.

@chrslg. Thanks. I appreciate the dtypes have to work the way they do, just wondering if there is a simple workaround to get the output I need.

Unfortunately (for you) the comparison is valid, if you have floats you have to mask the values after the comparison:
df['B'] = df['A'].gt(2).mask(df['A'].isna())

Alternatively, only compare the non-NA values:
m = df['A'].notna()
df.loc[m, 'B'] = df.loc[m, 'A'] > 2

# or
df['B'] = df['A'].dropna() > 2

Output:
     A      B
0  1.0  False
1  3.0   True
2  NaN    NaN

Note that this works as you expect with nullable integers (convert_dtypes):
df['B'] = df['A'].convert_dtypes() > 2

Output:
     A      B
0  1.0  False
1  3.0   True
2  NaN   <NA>


Thank you! df['B'] = df['A'].dropna() > 2 is elegant and does just what I need. Sorry I can't upvote your answer yet.

You can use pd.NA, then convert numbers to float on the way out, e.g.
Setup:
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('Int64')

Run your logic:
df['B'] = df['A'] > 2
df


Result (B is dtype boolean):
      A      B
0     1  False
1     3   True
2  <NA>   <NA>



Convert to float in order to pass to other libraries:
df['A'].astype('float')

0    1.0
1    3.0
2    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64


Thanks - this worked. I had to update pandas from 1.5 to 2.3 to prevent errors in the handling of casting pd.NA back to float (in case anyone else needs this).
